# Horizontal slide animation using jQuery 1.7.2.?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, transition

Can anyone suggest a way to implement a horizontal slide animation using the jQuery 1.7.2 library with out the jQueryUI library. So far with this set up I've managed to implement a vertical slide using

```
$('#selectorId').fadeIn(1000);
```

And a fade in using:

```
$('#selectorId').slideToggle('slow');
```

Also please not I have ruled out using CSS for the transition because as far as I can tell you can't do a call back function that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `animate` function: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5g1zwLe3/)

```
$('#toggle').click().toggle(function() {
    $('#box').animate({ width: 'hide' });
}, function() {
    $('#box').animate({ width: 'show' });
});
```

Originally found here: http://bueltge.de/test/jquery_horizontal_slide.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use the effects module from JQueryUI.

```
<a href="#" id="slidetoggle">
    Slide toggle the box
    <div id="box">This is the box that will be toggled</div>
</a>
```

JQuery

```
//hide box per default
$('#box').hide();
$('#slidetoggle').click(function() {
    $('#box').toggle('slide', 400);
    return false;
});
```

CSS(just to see some outlining)

```
#box {
    background: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #900;
    height: 135px;
    display: none; 
}
```

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HAQyK/1238/

Comment: Thanks for your answer unfortunately I cannot use jQueryUi:(