# How to get content to slide in on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css, slide

I just wondered how to get content blocks to slide in horizontally on scroll? It seems quite common on a lot of modern themes and I'm hoping to add this kind of effect on the homepage of http://brokernotes.co where we have the three 'how to' sections.

Any pointers on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25560695/945456) may help you. You'd then need to figure out how to tie it into whatever events are needed to trigger the behavior.

Comment: Also, the [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of way to achieve this.

I would highly recommend using JavaScript over anything else to tackle this challenge, and on top of that I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) where you can find some methods like `$.hide()` and `$.show()` which also allow you some nice animated transitions.

I also think that the example you provided relies on jQuery as well (they have jquery.min.js included as a script, etc.) so this is definitly the point where you want to start.

w3schools provides a tutorial series about jQuery where you can get started:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_examples.asp